# Eclipse Luna requested Java 1.8 but failed

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, version, eclipse-luna

I downloaded Eclipse Luna and ran from the terminal in Mac OS X:

```
> /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse
JavaVM: requested Java version (1.8.0) not available. Using Java at "/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home" instead.
```

However, I have:

```
> java -version
java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luna seems currently having a bug: it installs the wrong Java version as its own dependency and then fails claiming that version is wrong.

You need to install Java separately (download official SDK from Oracle website) and make that one default. Be sure you install SDK and not the web plugin. Type `java -version` to verify the version and then `which java` to tell the exact path. Edit `eclipse.ini` as usual and set there the correct path to Java executable.